# Is "sysServices" snmp-writable in netsnmp?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

The man page on snmpd.conf says that sysLocation/Contact/Name are snmp-writable, whereas sysDesc/ObjectID are not snmp-writable. How about sysServices?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the SNMPv2 MIB file, it states that sysServices is read-only.